How to prove limits that equal to zeta function for less than 1?
when I was solving a series I found these limits
$$ \lim_{m \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^m k^{\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{4m+1}{6} \sqrt{m+1}  \right) = \zeta \left(\frac{-1}{2} \right) \\ \lim_{m \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^m k^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{16m^2+12m+1}{40} \sqrt{m+1}  \right) = \zeta \left(\frac{-3}{2} \right) \\ \lim_{m \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^m k^{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{48m^3+60m^2+11m-1}{168} \sqrt{m+1}  \right) = \zeta \left(\frac{-5}{2} \right)  \\ \lim_{m \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^m k^{\frac{7}{2}}-\frac{256m^4+448m^3+144m^2-32m-5}{1152} \sqrt{m+1}  \right) = \zeta \left(\frac{-7}{2} \right)$$
So that show us
$$ \lim_{m \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^m k^{\frac{2n+1}{2}}-\Omega_{2n+1}(m) \sqrt{m+1}  \right) = \zeta \left(-\frac{2n+1}{2} \right) $$
where $\Omega_{2n+1}(m)$ is a polynomial with $n+1$ degrees
So how to find the polynomial $\Omega_{2n+1}(m)$ ?
and for more generalization how to find $A_n(m)$ such that
$$ \lim_{m \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k^n}-A_n(m) \right) = \zeta \left(n \right) $$
where $A(m)$ is a power function and $n<1$ because if $n>1$ then its clear that $A_n(m)=0$
EDITION
from the answer and the comment I got that
$$ A_{-n}(m)=\frac{m^{n+1}}{n+1} +\frac{m^{n}}{2}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2} \rfloor} \frac{(n-2i+2)!B_{2i}}{(2i)!} m^{n-2i+1} , n\ge0$$
and
$$ \Omega_{2n+1}(m)=\frac{2}{2n+3} (m+1)^{n+1}-\frac{(m+1)^n}{2}+\frac{n!}{(2n)!}\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac{2n+3}{4} \rfloor} \frac{(2n-4i+6)!4^{2i-3}B_{2i}}{(2i)!(n-2i+3)!} (m+1)^{n-2i+1}$$

There's a standard tool called Euler–Maclaurin summation that can be used (with some work) to find these polynomials.

As @GregMartin wrote in comments, this is very close to Euler-MacLaurin summation except that you introduced the unexpected factor $\sqrt{m+1}$.
For example, using this method, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^{\frac 92}=\zeta \left(-\frac{9}{2}\right)+\sqrt n \Bigg(\frac{2 n^5}{11}+\frac{n^4}{2}+\frac{3 n^3}{8}-\frac{7 n}{128}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \Bigg)$$ Now, make $n=m+1$ to make
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} k^{\frac 92}=\zeta \left(-\frac{9}{2}\right)+$$ $$\frac{256 m^5+1984 m^4+5904 m^3+8368 m^2+5603 m+1411}{1408}\,\sqrt{m+1}$$
